# Laravel, is it possible to delete part of array size?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an array as shown in the picture below. As you can see, the array have a total of 20 size. How do I cut it down to only 3 size? Do laravel have eloquent way of doing this?

[image]

**Answer by Muhammad Inaam Munir**

```
$null_index = 0; 
$current_index = 0; 

foreach ($rows as $key => $value) 
{ 

  $is_null = true; 
  foreach($value as $value_item) 
  { 
    if($value_item != null) 
    $is_null = false; 
    break; 
  } 

  if($is_null) 
  { 
    $null_index = $current_index; 
    break; // break the loop 
  } 

  $current_index++; 
} 


$rows = $rows->slice(0, $null_index); 

dd($rows);
```

Comment: You can use `->take()` or `->limit()` to get just some records :)

Comment: how about delete the rest?

Comment: no need to delete it will give filtered result and just take few records from data base

Comment: my original idea is that i wanted to insert new record in between the blue lines

Comment: ooh then it will be some diffrent

Comment: can you enlighten me?

Comment: @begineeeerrrr Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604242/5013099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slice method on Laravel Collection

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-slice

```
//convert array into laravel collection
$collection = collect($array);

// slice the collection starting from 0 index and limit upto 4 array values.
$slice = $collection->slice(0, 4);

// convert $slice back to array
$slice = $slice->toArray();

// now $slice variable has first 4 array values.
dd($slice);
```

Comment: does it delete the rest of the array? my original idea is that i wanted to insert new record in between the blue lines

Comment: yes, it deletes rest of the array. $slice has only 4 values now and rest has been deleted.

Comment: @begineeeerrrr i updated my answer to convert laravel collection back to array.

Comment: any idea how do i get the value 0 until 20 as shown in the picture? wanted to get the specific number at 3

Comment: @begineeeerrrr please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: it does not solved prob cause i havent tested since i dunno how to get the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151560/discussion-between-muhammad-inaam-munir-and-begineeeerrrr).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take`, it will show only three users:

```
 $data = User::get()->take(3);
```

Comment: he already has the array. now he wants to delete some data from the end of array.

Comment: ya i know that he wants only three data then he can use limit. how many array he wants to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` method which returns a slice of the collection starting at the given index

```
$collection = collect($array);
$slicedArray = $collection->slice(0, 4);
```

> my original idea is that i wanted to insert new record in between the blue lines

To insert item(s) into the position you can use `splice` method

```
$collection = collect($array);
$collection->splice(4, 0, $itemOrItemsArrayToInsert)
```